# Gaba and Magnesium

Tags: brain, pharmacology, psychoneuropharmacology

I read read that magnesium divalent ion binds to gaba receptors and induces the same effects as if gaba has binded. Does anyone know what happens to the gaba that would have been synthesised and otherwise bind to the gaba receptor if the magnesium divalent ion wasn't there. E.g is the gaba broken down, does it wait till the magnesium unbinds from the gaba receptor and then attaches itself to the gaba receptor?

Comment: Please give a reference/link/full citation of what “you read”. That way we can identify possible misunderstanding you may have of what you have read, which is suggested your writing “if the magnesium divalent ion wasn’t there, and renders the question unclear, at least to me.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you might still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 